# Find euclidean distance of two array of different length

Tags: php, ios, algorithm, similarity, euclidean-distance

I want to find Euclidean distance to check similarity of strings.

[image: Database Image]

From above image in a painting object field there are many image types in database. Images is displaying using this `paining_object` field. Now i want to show related images of one selected image by comparing strings from `paining_object` field. So i have used Euclidean distance method to find similarities of strings.

But i am facing issue with length. For ex. In first row from database there are four image types in `paining_object` field and in the second row there are more than four image types. So, how could i measure distance with this method for the arrays having unequal length.

Comment: Isn't Euclidean for geometrical distances? Maybe you are searching for [levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance?

Comment: but you actually don't want the similarity of strings but the similarity of arrays right? And all the more you don't want the similarity of arrays but of sets (since order does not matter: hellsing,katana==katana,hellsing ?)

Comment: @MarkusZeller The order of array elements matter for Levenshtein algorithm. But i don't want to consider ordered array.

Comment: We first need to clarify what you really want, as I don't really understand it. Do you want to know if the strings within the arrays are similar to each other or if the arrays themselves are similar? How can you use Euclidean Distance (distance between two points in a coordinate system) to measure similarity of strings?

Comment: I want to check similarity two arrays of string. @TobiasBrösamle

Comment: Under what circumstances are the arrays similar? When all the strings are similar? When all strings are identical but a defined amount of x strings? I think we do not have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did this by using Jaccard distance as below. First created two tables for unique object from where we can collect object from id and second where all object comes together seperated from (,)

1) **image_sub_main** Table

[image]

2) **image_main** Table

[image]

3) PHP file as Wordpress Way

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `image_main`");

$i=1;
$finimgarray = array();
$aa = array();
$bb = array();
$firstarray = array('similarity' =>100 , 'id' => $post_id[0]->id );

foreach($post_id as $key => $post){
    if($i < count($post_id)){
    $arraya =$post_id[0]->image_types;
    $a = explode(",",$arraya);
    $arrayb =$post_id[$i]->image_types;
    $b = explode(",",$arrayb);
    $array = array_unique (array_merge ($a, $b));
    $result=array_intersect($a,$b);
    $finalres = count($result) / count($array)*100 ;
    $finimgarray[] = array('similarity' =>round($finalres, 2) , 'id' => $post_id[$i]->id );
 }
    $i++;
}

array_push($finimgarray, $firstarray);
arsort($finimgarray);

foreach($finimgarray as $findimgarr){
  $id = $findimgarr['id'];
  $image = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM `image_main` WHERE `id` = $id ");
  echo "<img src='$image->image'/>";
}
```

**Your output will compare images to first one image and show according to similarity %**

Answer (score 2):

#### non euclidean distances

The distance between two unordered arrays can be rephrased as distance between sets.

A quick lookup shows there exists several distances representing the similarity between sets such as

- the [Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) distance

  d(a,b) = |a inter b| / |a union b|
- the maximum difference metric

  d(a,b) = 1 - |a inter b| / max(|a|, |b|)

there are more distances (for instance) on the paper [Distances between sets on set commonality](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X13004800)

#### still euclidean distance

You can still force it:

Get all your mangas as a vocabulary `V`, say size `n`. 
Consider the set `R^n`.

A row of your table can be represented as a vector `v` of `R^n`:
if the row contains word `i`, put `v[i] = 1`, `v[i]=0` otherwise

Finally the euclidean distance can trivially be applied on the vectors of same length.

distance thus be like

```
d(a,b) = || v_b - v_a ||_2 = sqrt( (v_b[0] - v_a[0])^2 + ... + (v_b[n-1] - v_a[n-1)^2)
```

Every square is equal to `1` iff `v_b[i]!=v_a[i]` that is you want to count the elements in `a` not in `b` U `b not in a` idem the symmetric difference of `a` and `b`.

You can thus rewrite your distance:

```
d(a,b) = sqrt(|a Δ b|)
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot apply [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) here because:

- The array lengths can be different
- The order of strings should not be considered. For example, *hellsing*
  can be at any index in the array. So, we should not compare the first element of the first array with the first element of the second array only.

Instead, we can define a similarity function which takes care of both the above problems - we can use the ratio of number of string matches to the total number of combinations as the similarity score.

```
// Assuming $firstArr and $secondArr are sets, i.e., don't contain duplicates
function similarityScore($firstArr, $secondArr) {
    $matchCount = 0;
    foreach ($firstArr as $first) {
        foreach($secondArr as $second) {
            if ($first == $second) {
                $matchCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $matchCount/(count($firstArr)*count($secondArr));
}
```

This function returns a real number in the range [0,1] where higher value indicates greater similarity.

Comment: I think you have not clear with my question. I want to use distance finding algorithm to check similarity. @hsin1.att214

Comment: @KomalGoyani I have updated my answer, please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @hsin1.att214 while it somehow provides a notion of similarity you do not define a distance. for instance with (firstArr,firstArr) the distance should be 0.

Comment: @user753642, thanks for pointing that out, may be we should use [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for finding the similarity of the sets.